# Did the Flash create the multiverse?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, the-flash-2023

In the film *The Flash (2023)*, Bruce Wayne states:

> If a person is stupid enough to mess with time... what you eventually end up with is this. The multiverse.

Assuming the Flash is the first time-traveler, does this mean the Flash created the multiverse?

***Note:** I am only interested in the context of this movie and what it establishes, not the comics or other media.*

Comment: Basically, yes. Although one could argue that the multiverse already exists and Barry moves between universes.